# ngIf=false with ngContent still loads template bindings

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-ngcontent

Defining a simple component as follows:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'loader',
  template: `<div *ngIf='false'>
        <ng-content></ng-content>
        </div>`,
})
export class Loader {}
```

When using it like this:

```
  <loader>
      {{model.something}}
  </loader>
```

I still get template binding errors if model is undefined in the parent, as it tries to resolve the bindings even with the `ngIf=false`. Why is this the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because inner content of `loader` component which is going to projected inside `ngContent` element, is get compiled once with the current component context (`this`), even if component template isn't injected to DOM.

It works the same way as `ng-transclude` work in Angular 1.X

You should use `Elvis Operator` here to avoid such issue

```
<loader>
    {{model?.something}}
</loader>
```

Comment: And you can still query it with `@ContentChild()` even when it is not transcluded to a `<ng-content>` element. It is just not added to the DOM.